# How to get the latest record for each device in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

I create a streaming table named device in DolphinDB to store the real-time data for 3000 devices. Now I want to query the last record for each device. How to write the sql statement?

The structure of this streaming table is as below:

```
Name        typeString  typeInt
----------  ----------  -------
time        DATETIME    11     
device_id   SYMBOL      17     
mem_free    LONG        5      
mem_used   LONG         5
```

Answer (score 0):

The query statement is as below:

```py
select top 1 * from t context by device_id csort time desc
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).